# IE fails to repeat background image in a modified Blogger page

Tags: html, css

Please bear with me as I'm fairly new to hand coding my web pages. I applied my CSS and HTML from the website I created to skin a Blogger page to match look and feel. Everything appears fine when testing in FireFox release 17.0.1, but the background for my div **#body_wrap** fails to repeat more than a few times in IE 8.

I'm probably missing something simple, but I would appreciate any help in determining the cause. I would like to know if it's IE related or just poor code that FireFox is picking up the slack on.

Here is the link to the blog:

http://www.zenmotostore.blogspot.com/

Here is the CSS for the div containers involved:

```
    #body_wrap {
    width: 1074px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    background: url(http://www.zenmotostore.com/images/repeat_bgd_shadow_blog.png) top repeat-y;
    clear: both;
    }

    #body_content_wrap {
    width: 984px;
    margin: 0px 45px 0px 45px;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    background: #000000;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    }

    #scrollofzen_header {
    width: 983px;
    height: 191px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #000000 url(http://www.zenmotostore.com/images/scroll_of_zen_header.jpg) top center no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    }
```

The div **#scrollofzen_header** sits above the Blogger content code in the HTML. Both are contained in the **#body_content_wrap** div.

Let me know if I need to include more code here on the post. Thanks in advace for any help you might have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be with this CSS declaration:

```
.body-fauxcolumn-outer
{
    background: url(http://www.zenmotostore.com/images/page_bgd_zen.jpg) #b8924f fixed no-repeat 50% top;
}
```

If I use the IE dev tools to disable this rule then the page seems to work fine (as I expect it to anyway).

Comment: This seems to have been the culprit. This was included in the body declaration in CSS. Separating them seems to have fixed the background repeat. I have since installed the Developer Tools to catch these kinds of issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be a clear issue.  Depends on version of IE.  You could look into css `height: 100%;`, or another way would be to add `<div class="clear></div>` as the last child element in `#body_wrap`.

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}

//then the markup

<div id="body_wrap">

    //Your content and stuff

    <div class="clear"></div>

<div> //close body_wrap
```

Answer (score -2):

Internet explorer has a big problem with using images in css. Whenever I try to use them it doesn't work. Not since the very latest edition of IE have they allowed background-images.

You need to define a height for the div that you want to have a background-image

Background Images aren't supported IE8 or below

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Comment: That sounds very wrong to me... Can you provide a reference that suggests that background-images and clarify what versions of IE you are talkign about... I've had no problem with background images in anything IE7 or up recently (I've not played with any earlier IE in some time).